# How to get the total sum in a for loop php

Tags: php

I am looking for the right syntax how to sum up a specific variable that I looped.
basically, I made a loop. This is the source code.

```
<?php
            $n = $_POST['n'];
            for ($i=1;$i<=$n;$i++) {
          ?>
            <h3 style="text-align:center"><b>ITEM <?php echo $i?>:</b></h3>
            <p>DESCRIPTION:</p>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="<?php echo $i.'description'; ?>" value="" autofocus>
            <p>PROGRAM UNIT:</p>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="<?php echo $i.'prog_unit'; ?>" value="" autofocus>
            <p>PROGRAM QUANTITY:</p>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="<?php echo $i.'prog_quantity'; ?>" min="0" value="0" step= ".001" autofocus>
            <p>PROGRAM UNIT COST:</p>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="<?php echo $i.'prog_unitcost'; ?>" min="0" value="0" step= ".00001" autofocus>
            <p>QUANTITY ACCOMPLISHED PREVIOUS:</p>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="<?php echo $i.'q_prev'; ?>" min="0" value="0" step= ".01" autofocus>
            <p>QUANTITY ACCOMPLISHED THIS REPORT:</p>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="<?php echo $i.'q_report'; ?>" min="0" value="0" step= ".01" autofocus>
            <p>QUANTITY ACCOMPLISHED TOTAL TO DATE:</p>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="<?php echo $i.'q_total_date'; ?>" min="0" value="0" step= ".01" autofocus>
            <p>PERCENT ACCOMPLISHED PREVIOUS:</p>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="<?php echo $i.'p_prev'; ?>" min="0" value="0.00" step= ".01" autofocus>
            <p>COST INCURRED:</p>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="<?php echo $i.'cost'; ?>" min="0" value="0" step= ".01" autofocus>
            <input type="hidden" name="n" value="<?php echo $n; ?>"><br>
                <?php }?>
```

This is the output of the code above.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9EPO.png)

And then, this is the syntax where I insert the looped values in to the database.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

  $n = $_POST['n'];
  for($i=1;$i<=$n;$i++)
  {
    $project = $_POST["project"];
    $description = $_POST[$i."description"];
    $prog_unit = $_POST[$i."prog_unit"];
    $prog_quantity = $_POST[$i."prog_quantity"];
    $prog_unitcost = $_POST[$i."prog_unitcost"];
    $prog_total = ($prog_quantity * $prog_unitcost);
    $q_prev = $_POST[$i."q_prev"];
    $q_report = $_POST[$i."q_report"];
    $q_total_date = $_POST[$i."q_total_date"];
    $p_prev = $_POST[$i."p_prev"];
    $p_report = ($q_total_date/$prog_quantity)*100;
    $cost = $_POST[$i."cost"];

    mysqli_query($bd,"insert into detailed_rpapi (project,description,prog_unit,prog_quantity,prog_unitcost,prog_total,q_prev,q_report,q_total_date,p_prev,p_report,cost)
     values ('$project','$description','$prog_unit','$prog_quantity','$prog_unitcost','$prog_total','$q_prev','$q_report','$q_total_date','$p_prev','$p_report','$cost')");

  }
  $sum = $prog_total + $prog_total;
  echo $sum;
  echo "Data Added Successfully ...";
}
```

I want to sum all the value from $prog_total. Please help me huhuhu

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are close. Instead of `$sum = $prog_total + $prog_total;`  try  `$sum = $sum + $prog_total;`

Read this, https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php,  and play with the code below.

```
<?php

$ImEqualtoI = 0;
$ImAlsoEqualtoI = 0;
$runningTotal = 0;
$runningTotal2 = 0;

for ($i=0; $i<10;$i++) {
    $runningTotal = $runningTotal + $i;
    $runningTotal2 += $i;
    
    ++$ImEqualtoI;
    $ImAlsoEqualtoI = $ImAlsoEqualtoI + 1;
}

var_dump($runningTotal, $runningTotal2, $ImEqualtoI, $ImAlsoEqualtoI, $i);

/*
int(45)
int(45)
int(10)
int(10)
int(10)
*/
```

**UPDATE**:
OK, I saw that one mistake and just assumed you were getting what you expected for `$_POST[$i."prog_quantity"];` or `$_POST[$i."prog_unitcost"];`.  Are those the expected values?

Comment: Hi, I tried $sum = $sum + $prog_total but it is still not working.

Comment: Well let's assume you are adding zero. Need to take a step back and make sure you are getting the expected values. Are you even looping the correct number of times? Can you debug with some `var_dump` and `die` statements maybe?

Comment: Yes, I am getting the expected value sir. But my problem is I don't know how to get the total sum under '$prog_total'.

Comment: `$sum = $sum + $prog_total;`  Needs to be **inside the loop**. After the loop, check the value of `$sum` for what you desire. Sorry, I kept overlooking problems. Hopefully we got there in the end! Suggest playing with my code example, looking at `foreach`, and using better structured multidimensional arrays. Read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42347889/input-field-with-variable-name-how-to-get-the-posted-values

Answer (score 0):

Notes:

- [No more than one element in the document or dialog may have the autofocus attribute. If applied to multiple elements the first one will receive focus.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/autofocus#:%7E:text=No%20more%20than%20one%20element%20in%20the%20document%20or%20dialog%20may%20have%20the%20autofocus%20attribute.%20If%20applied%20to%20multiple%20elements%20the%20first%20one%20will%20receive%20focus.)
- Repeatable forms are more elegantly produced with square-braced `name` attribute declarations.
- It will be more meaningful and improve the user experience to use `<label>` tags (instead of `<p>` tags) and relate them to your input elements using `for` and `id` -- these do not use square-brace naming syntax.
- For best security and stability, declare a prepared statements, bind the parameters by reference to expected variables to be declared by/in the loop, then only `execute()` the prepared statement from inside the loop.
- When binding the parameters, it may be less intuitive, but [it is safe to bind variables before or after they are declared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13845754/2943403).

Not all developer support the technique of using PHP to display HTML, but in your case, your from scripting might resemble:

```
<?php $n = $_POST['n'] ?? 1; ?>
<form name="yourForm" method="post" action="">
    <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= $n; ++$i) { ?>
        <h3 style="text-align: center"><b>ITEM <?php echo $i?>:</b></h3>
        <label for="description<?php echo $i; ?>">DESCRIPTION:</label>
        <input id="description<?php echo $i; ?>" type="text" class="form-control" name="description[]" value="" autofocus>
        <label for="prog_unit<?php echo $i; ?>">PROGRAM UNIT:</label>
        <input id="prog_unit<?php echo $i; ?>" type="text" class="form-control" name="prog_unit[]" value="">
        <label for="prog_quantity<?php echo $i; ?>">PROGRAM QUANTITY:</label>
        <input id="prog_quantity<?php echo $i; ?>" type="number" class="form-control" name="prog_quantity[]" min="0" value="0" step= ".001">
        <label for="prog_unitcost<?php echo $i; ?>">PROGRAM UNIT COST:</label>
        <input id="prog_unitcost<?php echo $i; ?>" type="number" class="form-control" name="prog_unitcost[]" min="0" value="0" step= ".00001">
        <label for="q_prev<?php echo $i; ?>">QUANTITY ACCOMPLISHED PREVIOUS:</label>
        <input id="q_prev<?php echo $i; ?>" type="number" class="form-control" name="q_prev[]" min="0" value="0" step= ".01">
        <label for="q_report<?php echo $i; ?>">QUANTITY ACCOMPLISHED THIS REPORT:</label>
        <input id="q_report<?php echo $i; ?>" type="number" class="form-control" name="q_report[]" min="0" value="0" step= ".01">
        <label for="q_total_date<?php echo $i; ?>">QUANTITY ACCOMPLISHED TOTAL TO DATE:</label>
        <input id="q_total_date<?php echo $i; ?>" type="number" class="form-control" name="q_total_date[]" min="0" value="0" step= ".01">
        <label for="p_prev<?php echo $i; ?>">PERCENT ACCOMPLISHED PREVIOUS:</label>
        <input id="p_prev<?php echo $i; ?>" type="number" class="form-control" name="p_prev[]" min="0" value="0.00" step= ".01">
        <label for="cost<?php echo $i; ?>">COST INCURRED:</label>
        <input id="cost<?php echo $i; ?>" type="number" class="form-control" name="cost[]" min="0" value="0" step= ".01">
    <?php } ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="project" value="<?php echo $project; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="n" value="<?php echo $n; ?>">
    <br>
</form>
```

Then the PHP script to receive the form submission might resemble:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $whiteList = ['project', 'description', 'prog_unit', 'prog_quantity', 'prog_unitcost', 'prog_total', 'q_prev', 'q_report', 'q_total_date', 'p_prev', 'p_report', 'cost'];
    $stmt = $db->prepare(
        'INSERT INTO detailed_rpapi (' . implode(',', $whiteList) . ') VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)'
    );
    $stmt->bind_param('ssssssssssss', $project, $description, $prog_unit, $prog_quantity, $prog_unitcost, $prog_total, $q_prev, $q_report, $q_total_date, $p_prev, $p_report, $cost);
    $project = $_POST['project'];
    $sum = 0;
    $inserts = 0;
    foreach (array_slice($_POST['description'], 0, $_POST['n'] ?? 0) as $i => $description) {
        $prog_unit = $_POST['prog_unit'][$i] ?? null;
        $prog_quantity = $_POST['prog_quantity'][$i] ?? 0;
        $prog_unitcost = $_POST['prog_unitcost'][$i] ?? 0;
        $prog_total = ($prog_quantity * $prog_unitcost);
        $q_prev = $_POST['q_prev'][$i] ?? 0;
        $q_report = $_POST['q_report'][$i] ?? 0;
        $q_total_date = $_POST['q_total_date'][$i] ?? 0;
        $p_prev = $_POST['p_prev'][$i] ?? 0;
        $p_report = !$prog_quantity ? 0 : (($q_total_date / $prog_quantity) * 100);
        $cost = $_POST['cost'][$i];

        // if performing any validation or sanitisation, do it here; use "continue" statement to prevent inserting invalid data.

        $stmt->execute();
        $sum += $prog_total;
        ++$inserts;
    }
    echo "Inserted $inserts rows. Total value: $sum";
}
```

<sub>Disclaimer: neither of these snippets were tested prior to posting this answer; if either snippet is flawed please leave an informative comment.</sub>